# Cut the corner off of a responsive image

Tags: css, image, svg, responsive-design

I have an image that has the corner cut off. The image has to be responsive so it can grow and shrink with the page. The image is managed by a CMS so it has to have the corner cut programmatically. The client won't be doing it manually before uploading.

I've can use SVG to outline the part of the image I need shown. Unfortunately I have to give a set path so it stops being responsive. I even tried creating a pattern that uses the image as a fill for the path

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 242 282" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="242" height="282" x="0" y="0">
            <image xlink:href="http://placehold.it/242x282" x="0" y="0" width="242" height="282" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 178 0 L 242 64 L 242 282 L 0 282 z" stroke="green" fill="url(#img1)"/>
</svg>
```

But that doesn't work because I have to give a absolute width and height. I also tried using clip-path but never seemed to work right.

Does anyone have any ideas or insights that might help me out here?

Here is an example of what the image needs to look like.
[image]

Comment: can you share screenshot of the page or particular area where you need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it stop being responsive?  As long as the viewBox is set correctly (as you have done), you can resize the container (eg. `<div>`) holding the SVG and it will resize with the div.

For example, try resizing the "Result" box in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bCJs9/

Comment: Whatever you do, you are going to have to customise the SVG with dimensions appropriate for each image.  SVG cannot automatically accommodate any size image.  You have to explicitly set the size of the graphic elements in the file.  You could however automatically generate suitable SVG using Javascript.

Comment: Does the triangular piece have to be transparent?  If it just needs to be the same colour as the background, then there are simpler solutions.

Comment: Of course, if all you wanted was just for the image to fill the rectangle, then there is this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KYv6e/1/

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about adding preserveAspectRatio to the image tag itself. I don't quite understand that attribute yet. I need to study it more.